# Matlab Neural Network correctly classified results

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I have trained a NN with Back Propagation algorithm and calculated the MSE. Now I want to find the percentage of correctly classified results (i am facing a classification problem). Any help?

Comment: Just take a set for which you know the right classification, let the classifier run and then you can calculate an estimate of the probability for correct classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your dataset whether you generate the data or whether you are given a dataset with samples.

In the first case you feed your NN with a generated sample and check whether NN predicts the correct class. You repeat it let say 100 times. And for each correctly classified sample you increment the counter CorrectlyClassified by one. Then the percentage of correctly classified results is equal to CorrectlyClassified. For higher accuracy you may not generate 100 samples, but X samples (where X is bigger than 100). Then the percentage of correctly classified results is:
`CorrectlyClassified/X*100`.

If you are given a dataset you should use **cross-validation**. See [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) for an example.